# How to insert image in tcpdf codeigniter from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, phpmyadmin, tcpdf

I want to display the image of the event i specifically chosen to generate to the pdf in codeigniter. Attached here is the snippet of my tcpdf code and a snippet in one of my views as to how i get the image from the database.

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA0MS.png)
[code of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1el.png)

```
//tcpdf code
$title = <<<EOD
<h3>QR Code</h3>
EOD;
$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '',$title, 0, 1, 0, true, 'C', true);

foreach($events as $event){
$image =    '';
}


$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $image, 0, 1, 0, true, 'C', true);

//sample view code as to how i get the image from database
<?php foreach ($events as $event): ?> 
    <img id="myImg" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/eventImages/<?php 
echo $event['eventImage']; ?>" alt="" >
```

[tcpdf code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tNuA.png)
[view sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bz70.png)

Comment: please post code as text, not an image.

Comment: @tim already attached it above. thank you.